# how to continue a bash script after it reboots the machine from the command after the reboot command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker

I'm working on a bash script for installing and setting up docker and run a application. The script needs to reboot the system and should continue after the reboot. I'm new with BASH, please help me getting through this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting everything that you need to execute after the reboot here:

```
/etc/rc.local
```